# In pandas dataframe, how to make one column act on all the others?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the small following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
 
value1 = [15, 20, 50, 70]
value2 = [15, 80, 45, 30]
base = [175, 150, 200, 125]

df = pd.DataFrame({"val1": value1, "val2": value2, "base": base})

df
    val1    val2    base
0   15      15      175
1   20      80      150
2   50      45      200
3   70      30      125
```

Actually, there are much more rows and much more `val***` columns...

I would like to express the figures given in the columns `val***` as percent of their corresponding `base` (in the **same** row); as an example, `70` (last in `val1`) should become `(70/125)*100`, (which is `56`), or `30` (last in `val2`) should become `(30/125)*100` (which is `28`) ; and so on for every figure.
I am sure the solution lies in a correct use of `assign` or `apply` and `lambda`, but I can't find how to do it ...

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `filter` the `val` like columns then divide these columns by the `base` column along `axis=0` followed by multiplication with `100` to calculate the percentage

```
df.filter(like='val').div(df['base'], axis=0).mul(100).add_suffix('%')
```

---

```
       val1%      val2%
0   8.571429   8.571429
1  13.333333  53.333333
2  25.000000  22.500000
3  56.000000  24.000000
```

Comment: Adding question: what if columns were just named "1", "2", "2", and so on (with no common text  "val" in their name). Would still had been possible to "filter" ?

Comment: In that case we can simply pass the list of column names that need to be selected. For example you could do like this `df[['1', '2', '3']].div(df['base'], axis=0).mul(100).add_suffix('%')
`